# Update a million records in MongoDb each with Subdocument that has a array which also needs to updated

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm a noobie in Nodejs and MongoDb so please excuse my silly doubts :D but i need help right now

```
{
"_id": "someid",
"data": "some_data",
"subData": [
    {
        "_id": "someid",
        "data": "some_data"
    },
    {
        "_id": "some_id",
        "data": "some_data"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have a schema like above and imagine i have millions of Documents in that schema, Now i want to update those Documents.

Based on condition i want to select a set of them and modify those "subdata" arrays and update them.

I know there is no way to do that in one query and the issue here at [Jira](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243) for that feauture but my question now is, **what is the most efficient way to update a million records in mongoDb ?**

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you please provide an example update operation on the `subdata` array?

Comment: add more code or example to be precise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going by the schema that you have posted here, it is good that you are maintaining a specific id for the sub document which is automatically added if you are using mongoose (in case the backend is node.js).

I would like to post something from the post that you have posted along with the main post of yours.

> It doesn't just not work for updating multiple items in one
>   array, it also doesn't work for updating a single item in an array for
>   multiple documents.

So our relevant option there goes out of the window. There is no way to update large chunks in single command as you'll have to target them individually.

If you are going to target them individually it is advisable that you target them using specific unique ids that are being generated and now to automate the whole process you can choose whichever efficient method suits the backend you are using.

You can make several processes in parallel that would help you to attain the desired task in less time but it wont be possible to do everything in one go because mongodb don't support that.

It is also advisable that at place of maintaining several sub documents you should just go for separate collection instead as it'll ease the whole process. Maintain a field to map your two collections.

References

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-831
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-1243
https://www.nodechef.com/docs/cloud-search/updates-documents-nested-in-arrays